# Extracting Shape Context Descriptors to train SVM

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, shapes, svm, feature-extraction

I am working on a project that deals with classifying images based only on the shape obtained (binary image) after background subtraction. I want to extract shape context descriptors from the two classes and train an SVM classifier.
How can I extract shape context descriptors ? Please tell me if there is any implementation or implementation guide to extract shape context descriptors for training SVM.

Answer (score 1):

These links might help you find code for shape context: [(1)](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/shape/sc_digits.html) and [(2)](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~zhengyf/PointMatching.htm).

[This tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html) is quite clear on how to use OpenCV's implementation of SVM for classification.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here http://answers.opencv.org/question/1668/shape-context-implementation-in-opencv/

Hope this helps,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Digits classification can be done based on shapes, using HOG features. The link below contains Matlab code for this :

http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html